# Angular - Retrieve DOM Element by POJO It's Bound To

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

If I have this . . .

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
</div>
```

and this, in a controller . . .

```
$scope.items = [ { name: "a" }, { name: "b" } ];
```

and this variable . . .

```
var myVariable = $scope.items[1];
```

Can I find the DOM element that was created by an ng-repeat given only myVariable?  It will now look like this:

```
{ name: "b", $$hashKey: "043" }
```

Can I use some Angular magic (or even my knowledge of $$hashKey) to look up the element that corresponds to this object?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? My bet is there is a simpler way to do whatever it is you need

Comment: I want to animate a set of elements.  I was using a loop to do it the Angular way, and it works fine on desktop PCs,m but on mobile devices it's far too slow.  I want to do the same thing with far fewer $digests and do a pure jQuery animation.  I'm looking for the performant way rather than the right way, so that's why I'm trying to go under the hood here . . .

Comment: can use a directive , within `ng-repeat` a child scope is created for each element, can check for `scope.$last` in directive and then fire off your animation code

Comment: depending on the animations you need to do, and browsers you need to support, if you want good performance go with css-based animations over js-based animations when possible. Also look into requestAnimationFrame when working with js-based animation.